# Cubist Add-In for ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, raster, add-in

I'm looking for an ArcMap add-in that will create a raster based on rules from RuleQuest Research's Cubist .model files. Ideally, the add-in will give the user the option of matching input raster data to the variable names defined in the .model file. Does anyone know of such a product? I have done ArcGIS.com and Google searches without any luck.

Comment: This looks awfully obscure. A [quick search](http://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=cubist&t=content) on arcgis.com yields nothing. Perhaps you could develop it yourself? :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it's obscure. I thought I would ask the community before making un-needed work for myself.

Comment: Understandable. I did find a mention of it here, you might ask them how they used it: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=e1e5eca1ed544f07a7896243b8b9f980